# Difficulty with inheritance in PyQt

Tags: python, qt

I'm trying to run an example from the book "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT" and I'm getting an error message.

```
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an Expression and press enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()

        layout = QBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()

        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),self.UpdateGUI)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ryans App")

def UpdateGUI(self):
    try 
        text = self.lineedit.text()
        self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s</b>" % (text,eval(text)))
    except:
        self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s is Invalid!</font>" % text )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

The trace I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MyName\workspaces\LearningProject\src\LearningModule.py", line 33,   in <module>
form = Form()
File "C:\Users\MyName\workspaces\LearningProject\src\LearningModule.py", line 16,  in __init__
layout = QBoxLayout()
TypeError: QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.Direction, QWidget parent=None): not enough arguments
```

I'm confused as to why it's requiring an argument to create the Form object as I'm just trying to inherit from QDialog... am I missing a subtlety in the syntax?

Comment: You need to specify a direction (e.g. `QBoxLayout.LeftToRight`) and optionally a parent (in this case, `self` should work as the parent) on your `layout = QBoxLayout()` line.

Comment: that works!  Thanks!  Do you mind putting your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a `QBoxLayout`, you need to specify a direction (e.g. `QBoxLayout.LeftToRight`) and optionally a parent (in this case, `self` should work as the parent). 
These should be added on your `layout = QBoxLayout()` line.

Comment: It's probably better to avoid using `QBoxLayout` directly and use `QVBoxLayout` or `QHBoxLayout` instead, unless it's really necessary to choose layout direction at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The version I have uses QVBoxLayout instead:

```
...
self.lineedit.selectAll()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(self.browser)
...
```

My understanding is that since it lines the widgets up vertically, the .LeftToRight and parent are not strictly necessary.

I'm using the most recent code archive for python 2.6 from the book website.

Comment: Thanks for the info, after looking closer I see the version I have also uses QVBoxLayout and it works when it is as you have above.